# Kubeadm alpha phase certs causes join command token to be invalid

Tags: kubernetes

I have used `kubeadm alpha phase certs` to recreate the certificates used in my Kubernetes cluster.  Also, use the alpha phase for kubeconfig.  Now when trying to join a new worker - it is giving me errors that my token is invalid even when the token has been regenerate 3 times using - `kubeadm token create --print-join-command`.

The error that I keep getting is:

```
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://x.x.x.x:6443"
[discovery] Failed to connect to API Server "x.x.x.x:6443": token id "bvw4cz" is invalid for this cluster or it has expired. Use "kubeadm token create" on the master node to creating a new valid token
```

Anyone run into the same problems or have a suggestion? 
Thanks!

EDIT-- 
This is the tail end of /var/log/syslog --

Nov  5 09:40:01 master01 kubelet[755]: E1105 09:40:01.892304     755 kubelet.go:2236] node "master01" not found
Nov  5 09:40:01 master01 kubelet[755]: E1105 09:40:01.928937     755 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://x.x.x.x:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dkubernetserver&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")
Nov  5 09:40:01 master01 kubelet[755]: E1105 09:40:01.992427     755 kubelet.go:2236] node "master01" not found

EDIT 2 - 1. Now the real question is - if regenerating certs do not enable trust to itself as a CA, how do you fix this problem? 2. Is this a problem that is well known?

Comment: can you provide steps to recreate this issue?

Comment: I've promoted 1 cluster and 1 linux worker node through use of Kubeadm with basic settings.  Installed Flannel after. Then used commands to regenerate Certificates because I needed extra names in the Certificate SANs. Ran these commands -- mkdir /etc/kubernetes/pkibak
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/* /etc/kubernetes/pkibak
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/*
kubeadm alpha phase certs all --apiserver-advertise-address=0.0.0.0 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=x.x.x.x,x.x.x.x
systemctl restart docker
kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig admin \
  --cert-dir /etc/kubernetes/pki \
  --kubeconfig-dir /tmp/.